# How to map each item from observable to another one that comes from async function?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I want to

1.map item from observable to another one if it has already saved in database.

2.otherwise, use it as it is.

and keep their order in result.

Saved item has some property like tag, and item from observable is 'raw', it doesn't have any property.

I wrote code like this and run testMethod.

```dart
    class Item {
      final String key;
      String tag;
      Item(this.key);
      @override
      String toString() {
        return ('key:$key,tag:$tag');
      }
    }

    class Sample {
    ///this will generate observable with 'raw' items.
    static Observable<Item> getItems() {
        return Observable.range(1, 5).map((index) => Item(index.toString()));
    }

    ///this will find saved item from repository if it exists.
    static Future<Item> findItemByKey(String key) async {
        //simulate database search
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        if (key == '1' || key == '4') {
            final item = Item(key)..tag = 'saved';
            return item;
        } else
            return null;
    }

    static void testMethod() {
        getItems().map((item) async {
            final savedItem = await findItemByKey(item.key);
            if (savedItem == null) {
                print('not saved:$item');
                return item;
            } else {
                print('saved:$savedItem');
                return savedItem;
            }
        }).listen((item) {});
    }
```

The result is not expected one.

expected:

```
saved:key:1,tag:saved
not saved:key:2,tag:null
not saved:key:3,tag:null
saved:key:4,tag:saved
not saved:key:5,tag:null
```

actual:

```
not saved:key:2,tag:null
not saved:key:3,tag:null
not saved:key:5,tag:null
saved:key:1,tag:saved
saved:key:4,tag:saved
```

How to keep their order in result?

Comment: so you dont "map" your items with another `Observable` but with simple `Future` - so simple: `Future findItemByKey(Item item) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  if (item.key == '1' || item.key == '4') 
    item.tag = 'saved';
  return item;
}

void testMethod() {
  Sample.getItems().asyncMap(findItemByKey).listen(print);
}` will do the trick

Comment: and if you **really** want to "map" with another `Observable` use `flatMap`, `concatMap` or `switchMap`

Comment: @pskink I want to map with anoher `Future`, so this time I'll use asyncMap. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I answer myself to close this question.**

According to pskink's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399100/how-to-map-each-item-from-observable-to-another-one-that-comes-from-async-functi?noredirect=1#comment99405976_56399100), use asyncMap or concatMap solve my problem. Thanks!!

below is new implementation of testMethod.

asyncMap version:

```dart
getItems().asyncMap((item) {
  final savedItem = findItemByKey(item.key);
  if (savedItem != null)
    return savedItem;
  else
    return Future.value(item);
}).listen(print);
```

concatMap version:

```dart
getItems().concatMap((item) {
  final savedItem = findItemByKey(item.key);
  if (savedItem != null)
    return Observable.fromFuture(savedItem);
  else
    return Observable.just(item);
}).listen(print);
```